# Unable to create multiple versions of a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code, below, that tries to place multiple folder icons at the top of a gallery pane. The AJAX call retrieves the folder information which is just a string that looks like:

```
"boots,50,120,socks,50,160,shoes,50,200,"
```

where, in this case, there are three folders: "boots" located at top=50, left=120, socks etc.

For each folder in the returned data the code tries to create a div, containing a folder icon, position it  according to the data from the AJAX call and append it to the DOM. But something is very wrong because I'm producing multiple multiple folders with the same name and same offset.

```
$.post('ajax.php', {op : 'get_folders'},       
  function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {  
    var folderDiv;
    var folders =     responseTxt.split(",");

    for (i=0; i<folders.length; i=i+3){
      name=folders[i];
      posTop=folders[i+1];
      posLeft=folders[i+2];

      folderDiv = '<div class=openclosed_folder_icon>' +
                  '<img class="folder_icon" src="images/folder_closed.png"  alt="closed folder"  />' +
                  '<div class="folder_name" >name</div>' + 
                  '</div>';

      $(folderDiv).find('.folder_name').text(name);
      $(folderDiv).attr({'id' : name});
      $(folderDiv).draggable(folder_icon_dragOps)
                  .css({'cursor'     : 'pointer',
                        'position'   : 'absolute',
                        'top'        : posTop,
                        'left'       : posLeft
                       }) 
                  .appendTo('#galleryHeader');
  } 
});
```

Does anyone see a problem with this code?

Comment: Every time you do `$(folderDiv)`, you are *re-creating* the DOM element and making a *new* jQuery object.

Comment: First time I'm seeing the position of an element coming from server side as part of a long string... BTW, can you share the minimal HTML/CSS that goes with this which is required to reproduce what you've so far..?

Comment: Be careful with the trailing comma in your `responseTxt`.  Your `folders` array will have an 10th element, a blank string.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it does and I've handled it by changing the for-loop to run until i<folders.length-1.  The position file is updated by the stop_drag event for the element and I never know if this will be the last folder to be dragged so it's not easy to just leave off the final comma for the last drag. It's easier to always write all three commas and handle it in the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you do `$(folderDiv)`, you are *re-creating* the DOM element and making a *new* jQuery object.  You need to call `$(folderDiv)` **once**, and save it into a variable.

```
var folderDiv = '<div class=openclosed_folder_icon>' +
       '<img class="folder_icon" src="images/folder_closed.png"  alt="closed folder"  />' +
       '<div class="folder_name">'+name'+</div>' + 
        '</div>';
var $folderDiv = $(folderDiv); // Convert this into a DOM element, and save the jQuery object

// Do actions on the saved jQuery object, so that you are editing the *same* DOM element

// You can chain together these calls
$folderDiv.find('.folder_name').text(name).attr({'id' : name});
$folderDiv.draggable(folder_icon_dragOps).css({
    'cursor':'pointer',
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': posTop,
    'left': posLeft
}).appendTo('#galleryHeader');
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how your code will let me end up with three separate folder divs ("boots", "socks", and "shoes" in this case) in the DOM.

Comment: What does your `name` variable contain?  Isn't that each of the names?

Comment: Yes. But if all of your code is in the for-loop it will be executed each time.

Comment: Yes, yes it will.  Each time, it'll create a *new* div.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want: three separate folders. Are you saying that doing $(folderDiv).find() and $(folderDiv).attr() and $(folderDiv).draggable() each pass  recreates the DOM element three times and that's causing a problem?

Comment: @Steve: Yeah.  `folderDiv` is an HTML string.  When you do `$(folderDiv)` (each time), jQuery (re-)creates a new DOM element.  That could cause an issue.